"I meant to do something" VS "I was going to do something". | Are they the same in meaning?
Someone living in the UK is answering a question about their house in Florida during the hurricane:
"I meant to ask my parents, because I have been home this week, and I have been seeing my family, and I forgot to ask."
The use of "meant to do something" reminded me of "was/were going to do something". As a non-native speaker, they both seem to have the same meaning.
So, I wonder if the speaker had said "I was going to ask my parents .....", would it have meant the same?

It's just the verb "mean" in the dictionary sense "intend".

I meant to ask specifically means 'at that time I had the intention of asking'.
I was going to ask could be used to mean the same, but was going to can also refer to something the speaker was actually about to do, rather than an intention they forgot about. "I was just going to boil the kettle when there was a power cut." (outage in American English.)

Thanks, very well explained.
